# How to read from .csv file with TextFieldParser using a specified date format?

Tags: c#, csv, datetime-format, textfieldparser

**EDIT: This question was based off me misunderstanding Excel's behavior. I kept thinking the M/DD/YYYY format was in the input file but that was only Excel's reformatting of it, the TextFieldParser did indeed keep the original format YYYY-MM-DD. Thanks everyone for leading me to this conclusion.**

I am reading from a .csv file for a console app using the TextFieldParser class in C# as follows:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\myfilepath"))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited; //set up parser
    parser.SetDelimiters(",", "|");

    string[] header = parser.ReadFields(); //process header
}
```

The format of dates in the input file is `M/DD/YYYY`. However, I need the format to be something else, say `MM/DD/YYYY`.

When the TextFieldParser reads date fields, it changes them to the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, which I see in my output, so I know it is somehow recognizing fields that look like dates and converting them to a specific format. My problem boils down to simply changing this format. Hopefully there is some way to do this...

I know I could simply edit the strings of the dates after the parser has read them, but this seems sloppy to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your sample input data?

Comment: If you parse them to Date variables, the text file format becomes irrelevant.  You should know that tools such as CSVHelper will read, parse and type the data into classes and collection for you

Comment: @Sach, no I can't. The information is sensitive. Whether opened in Notepad, WordPad, Excel, etc. the date format is M/DD/YYYY (if that was what you were wondering).

Comment: I don't need actual data, but a sample. And it's suspicious that date format is M/DD/YYYY because does it never show months after September? And do you have to stick with `TextFieldParser`? The `CSVHelper` nuget package is much better equipped to handle CSV files.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. I used input text like this `5/23/2018` and it read as is using your code. Please provide full relevant code and sample data.

Comment: @Sach Thanks for pointing out this is not reproducible. That led me to see what was actually happening (Excel was reformatting the dates in the input file).

Answer (score 2):

Per MSDN [TextFieldParser.ReadFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields), TextFieldParser.ReadFields() - Reads all fields on the current line, returns them **as an array of strings**

Tried with following line in csv file:

```
     1,2019-10-04,04/10/2019,test
```

This works:

```
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"<path to testcsv.csv>"))
                {
                    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited; 
                    parser.SetDelimiters(",", "|");

                    string[] current = parser.ReadFields();
                    string[] formats = new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
                    foreach (string f in current)
                    {
                        DateTime dv ;
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(f, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dv))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"found date - { dv.ToLongDateString()}");
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"found something  - {f}");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you, don't know why it wasn't accepted as an answer